# Xcode -- move all classes in a group to the finder folder of that group?

Tags: iphone, xcode, file

Suppose that group A has its path set to folder A in the finder, and group B has its path set to folder B.  I move one of my classes from group B to group A.  Annoyingly, the default behavior is that the file remains in folder B in the finder, and Xcode sets the path for the file to something like "../B/ClassName.extension"

Is there a way to change this behavior so that in the above scenario, the file moves to folder A in the finder?  Or, alternatively, a relatively painless way to move it afterwards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a solution to this - This is a similar question, but no one has come up with an answer there. [How do i consolidate my xcode project files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/791854/how-do-i-consolidate-my-xcode-project-files)

Seems like doing it manually is the only way to go unfortunately!

Answer (score 0):

File grouping in Xcode isn't a reflection of the underlying file structure, nor does it particularly need to be. I've never understood there to be any real logic in where Xcode creates files within a project's directory, but I've never cared much because I can group them manually inside the project (not the filesystem) however I want.